# Move Rows in Microsoft Word Tables

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

I have seen the following shortcut cited ([example](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/8-formatting-tips-perfect-tables-microsoft-word/)) as a way to move table rows around in Microsoft Word tables: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>

However, I have been unable to successfully use this shortcut in Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus 2016. Is this shortcut still active?

Comment: Do you mean the on-line version of Word, or the installed one?

Comment: The offline version, installed locally.

Comment: This is very much alive and I just tested this on the German and US keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed that this works in Office 2016.  (Was unaware that this was possible until your question. Useful feature.) Also works with multiple adjacent rows when they are selected before keyboard shortcut.  Try using some other shortcuts that use the Alt key to see if there is something wrong with the key itself.  (If there were something wrong with the shift or arrows, I assume you would have noticed.)

Comment: Thank you for confirming that this feature works! On you suggestion, I have tried other Word shortcuts that involve **Alt** -- all of these work. For some reason, though, **Alt + Shift + Up/Down Arrow** still doesn't work for me! Maybe it's a problem with my normal document template?